# date picker issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i need to add a date picker to my site(live score site) i need to change the fixtures depending on the selected date.
i have tried a lot of jquery datepickers but i always get the same problem which is :
i cant change the fixtures when i select a new date i tried jquery events (select , change, live ,.....) nothing work also i can not get the date picked from the text box to get the related fixtures? 
this is a sample code for what i am working on (i cant even alert on change):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="zebra_datepicker.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // assuming the controls you want to attach the plugin to 
    // have the "datepicker" class set
    $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();

 });
 $(".datepicker").change(function(){alert('basel')});
    </script>
    </head>
<body><input type="text" name="your_input" class="datepicker"/></body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
```

i hope to get an answered soon thx

Comment: You should read the datepickers' documentation. Most of them implement their own onchange event, Zebra seems to use `onSelect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI overrides the change function, so you want to use the jQueryUI events, such as onSelect.

```
$('input.datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { alert("Test"); }
});
```

Of course all of this is in the documentation:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Comment: thank you very much i did not notice the override thing and the link helped me a lot.